# How to create the same hyperlink for every n+x row?

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I would like to create a hyperlink for every n + 44 rows, starting with row 42 (i.e. rows 42, 86, 130....), between row 42 to row 85930.

```vb
Sub BackToKTOHyperlinks()
    
    Dim i_counter As Long
    
    For i_counter = 42 To 85930
    
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Range("C" + CStr(i_counter)), Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & Sheet6.Name & "'!A11", TextToDisplay:="Back to Key Tasks Overview"
    
        i_counter = i_counter + 44
    
    Next i_counter
    
End Sub
```

There is an error here because the second i_counter brings me to **row** 43+44=**87** for the second hyperlink, which is not what I want.

As a bonus, is it possible to have the hyperlink bring users back to their last clicked cell on Sheet6 without having to go to a specific cell (Cell A11 here)?

Comment: `For i_counter = 42 To 85930 Step 44`  Typically you don't modify the loop counter in a For...Next loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use modulo operator to add link in row when a mod b = 0 and place corrected range in target range

```
Sub BackToKTOHyperlinks()
Dim i_counter As Long

For i_counter = 1 To 85930 - 42
    If i_counter = 1 Then
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Range("C" + CStr(i_counter + 41)), Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & Sheet6.Name & "'!A11", TextToDisplay:="Back to Key Tasks Overview"
    End If  '   If i_counter = 1
    If i_counter Mod 44 = 0 Then
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Range("C" + CStr(i_counter + 42)), Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & Sheet6.Name & "'!A11", TextToDisplay:="Back to Key Tasks Overview"
    End If  '   If i_counter Mod 44 = 0
Next i_counter
End Sub
```

if You want do go back to last selected range in sheet6 You need to define global variable for wiole workbook like `Public rng_Sheet6LastRange as Range` in any standard module and add `rng_Sheet6LastRange =target.address` to `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event on sheet6 code. Then You can replace `"'!A11"` by `rng_Sheet6LastRange` . ofc You need add condition checked that `not rng_Sheet6LastRange  Is Nothing` to protect from crash